# TYPO3 v11 and fluidtypo3/flux v9.5.0: Class Page does not exist. Reflection failed

Tags: typo3, flux

I did a fresh composer installation of TYPO3 v11.5.9...

```
composer require "typo3/cms-adminpanel:^11.5" "typo3/cms-backend:^11.5" "typo3/cms-belog:^11.5" "typo3/cms-beuser:^11.5" "typo3/cms-core:^11.5" "typo3/cms-dashboard:^11.5" "typo3/cms-extbase:^11.5" "typo3/cms-extensionmanager:^11.5" "typo3/cms-filelist:^11.5" "typo3/cms-fluid:^11.5" "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content:^11.5" "typo3/cms-form:^11.5" "typo3/cms-frontend:^11.5" "typo3/cms-impexp:^11.5" "typo3/cms-info:^11.5" "typo3/cms-install:^11.5" "typo3/cms-lowlevel:^11.5" "typo3/cms-opendocs:^11.5" "typo3/cms-recordlist:^11.5" "typo3/cms-recycler:^11.5" "typo3/cms-redirects:^11.5" "typo3/cms-reports:^11.5" "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor:^11.5" "typo3/cms-scheduler:^11.5" "typo3/cms-seo:^11.5" "typo3/cms-setup:^11.5" "typo3/cms-tstemplate:^11.5" "typo3/cms-viewpage:^11.5"
```

and added fluidtypo3/flux, composer installed v9.5.0:

```
composer require fluidtypo3/flux
```

I created a sitepackage with [sitepackagebuilder.com](https://sitepackagebuilder.com/).
In the ext_localconf.php I registered Flux like this:

```
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('Vendor.Sitepackage', 'Content');
\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('Vendor.Sitepackage', 'Page');
```

After adding a root page, creating a main template record, including all static templates and adding the TypoScript to the page, I opened the page in the frontend. The following error occured:

```
(1/2) #1278450972 TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Reflection\Exception\UnknownClassException
Class Page does not exist. Reflection failed.
```

No matter what extension settings are defined or if any templates are present in `Resources/Private/Tempaltes/Content/`, the exception persists.

But, if I change the version of Flux to `dev-development`, the frontend loads perfectly fine.

Does anybody know what's going on here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems, there is a bug in v9.5.0 of flux which has been already fixed in `develepment`-branch of the project. You can use (for the moment) the dev-version - or you have to wait for the next release.

Comment: Thx a lot for your help! I'm just wondering that nobody had this issue before. TYPO3 11 is out since October and Flux 9.5 has been released in May last year. This combination is not working at all. Though I can't find any complaints or tickets. So I thought it must be my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The file `ext_localconf.php` has a faulty condition to check the TYPO3 core version, which leads to a wrong `$pageControllerName` (row 136). It's `Page`instead of `\FluidTYPO3\Flux\Controller\PageController::class` which explains the exception message. (The wrong condition also occurs in file `Classes/Integration/ContentTypeBuilder.php`).

This bug has been fixed in branch `development` commit `#19279684f1792f373d3a1fafdbde4dea0e4e12d9`.